# jQuery event trigger + constructor pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, constructor, new-operator

I create an object with "new", initialize it and subscribe to it's event with `$(this).trigger({type:"myevent", field1:val1})`, like (**[here - jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alex440/T7LgK/)** ), and it works:

```
var Users = function (selector) {
        var that = this;
        var myButton;

        //function to trigger
        function add(name) {
            console.log("before trigger for: $('"+selector+"') with ["+name+"]")

            $(that).trigger({
                type: "user-added",
                name: name,
                date: new Date(),
            });
        }

        $(selector).click(function () {
            add($("#name").val());
        });
    };
```

My problem is that I am interested to pass the `selector` in a separate function `init` (**[another jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alex440/t9GBD/)**):

```
        var Users = function () {
            var that = this;

            var mySelector;

            //function to trigger
            function add(name) {

                console.log("before trigger for: $('" + mySelector + "') with [" + name + "]")

                $(that).trigger({
                    type: "user-added",
                    name: name,
                    date: new Date(),
                });
            }

            function init(selector) {
                mySelector = selector;
                $(selector).click(function () {
                    add($("#name").val());
                });
            }

            return {
                init: init
            };
        };
```

In this case the code is breaking:

When the event is triggered, the `that` object the function sees looks like
 `Users {}`,

and not updated like in the working sample:
`Users {jQuery11111210404012482791554801678404482030027643403015099466: Object}`,

so jQuery does not trigger the event.

Sure I can set `that` in `init()`, or initialize the object in the constructor to solve the problem, but it drives me crazy why the `"that"` member does not get hooked up to the actual object if I set it in the constructor and hookup to the event in an inner function, but does work if I hookup to the event in the same function.

Thanks.

Comment: "*that object the function sees looks like `Users {}`*" - well, that's what it *is*. What else would you have expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>         return {
>             init: init
>         };
> ```

You shouldn't `return` anything from a constructor that is being invoked [with `new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new). The [`this` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) which your `that` refers to *is* an empty `User` instance, but not the plain object with the `init` function you returned, assigned to `u1` and installed the handlers upon.

Instead of returning that object literal, you should just do

```
         this.init = init;
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. Should brush up my knowledge on this matter, I see I developed some cargo cult here...

Answer (score 0):

First, in passing in your selector, try:

```
var u = new Users($("#but1"));
```

As for passing selector on the outside, set:

```
var mySelector;
```

On the outside of the 'Users' function, this way any other function can overwrite the value of the variable, as well as keep its last value regardless of how many times you run the 'Users'. Then set your selector dynamically as such:

```
mySelector = $("#but1");
```

Comment: not sure I understand you (By the way I tried the first 2 edits of the answer and it didn't work).

do you mean set {return selector:mySelector} and then hookup to mySelector.click()? in this case it won't work, cos the hookup is in the init function, I can't do it in the constructor.

Comment: Here I forked over your JSFiddle, with my changes in tow, hope it works, I just re-updated it:

http://jsfiddle.net/9JYQW/3/

Comment: well, I don't see the changes, it seems the same and still not working... Anyway Bergi gave the correct solution - we should've assign the init to this, and not return... I accepted his answer... Thanks anyway! Have a great day.